# how to extract elements from a string with a trasversal loop

Tags: python-2.7

I have this little code:

```
> def names():
    prefixes='JKLMNOPQ'
    suffix='ack'
    for letter in prefixes:
        if letter == 'O'or 'Q' in prefixes:
            print  letter +'u' +suffix
        else:
            print letter+suffix
```

And I would like to achieve the following format after printing it:

```
Jack
Kack
Lack
Mack
Nack
Ouack
Pack
Quack
```

However I get this one:

```
Juack
Kuack
Luack
Muack
Nuack
Ouack
Puack
Quack
```

For any reason I cannot see the if statement is not work. How can I manage to make it work?

Comment: Accept an answer if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is you have a "always" `True` condition:

```
def names():
    prefixes='JKLMNOPQ'
    suffix='ack'
    for letter in prefixes:
        if letter == 'O'or 'Q' in prefixes:     # here
            print  letter +'u' +suffix
        else:
            print letter+suffix
```

`'Q'` is always in `prefixes` - the condition is alwas `True`.

Use `if letter in 'O Q':` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You probably might want to change your code to:

```
def names():
    prefixes='JKLMNOPQ'
    suffix='ack'
    for letter in prefixes:
        if letter == 'O' or letter == 'Q':
            print  letter +'u' +suffix
        else:
            print letter+suffix
```